# d3.js - draw arrow line from border to border

Tags: svg, d3.js

I saw some topic discuss about border to border connection but my case is special, it connect with quartic curve so not easy to calculate the exact position!

```js
console.clear()

var w = 15

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width','500')
.attr('height','500')
.attr('viewBox',`0 0 ${w} ${w}`)
//.style('border','1px solid red')
add_marker(svg)
add_grid(svg)
draw(svg)

function add_marker(svg) {  
  var color = 'black'  
  svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id","arrowhead")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 7)
    .attr("orient","auto")
    .attr('refX',5)
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 5 2 L 0 4 z")
    .style("fill", color);
}

function px(r,a) {
  return r*Math.cos(a*Math.PI/180)
}
function py(r,a) {
  return r*Math.sin(a*Math.PI/180)
}

function draw() {
  var r = 5
  var dots = [0,60,120,180,240,300,360]
  var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${r+2},${r+2})`)

  var g1 = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(dots).enter()
  
  g1.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',d => px(r,d))
  .attr('cy',d => py(r,d))
  .attr('r',1)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  
  var prev = null
  var mydraw = function(d,i) {
    if (prev == null) {
      prev = d
      return ''
    }
    var x1 = px(r,d)
    var y1 = py(r,d)
    var x2 = px(r,prev)
    var y2 = py(r,prev)
    var x3 = px(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var y3 = py(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var path = `M ${x1},${y1} Q ${x3},${y3} ${x2},${y2}`
    prev = d
    return path
  }
  g1.append('path')
  .attr('d',d => mydraw(d))
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  .attr("marker-end","url(#arrowhead)")
}
function add_grid(svg) {
  var mygrid = function(d) {
    return `M 0,${d} l ${w},0 M ${d},0 l 0,${w}`
  }

  var grid = []
  for(var i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    grid.push(i);
  }

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(grid).enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d',d => mygrid(d))
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','green')
    .attr('stroke-width',.05)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It will be cool if d3 can just shrink \r then it work perfect in this case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `qbPath` function to draw a path from border to border:

```js
var w = 15

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width','500')
.attr('height','500')
.attr('viewBox',`0 0 ${w} ${w}`)
//.style('border','1px solid red')
add_marker(svg)
add_grid(svg)
draw(svg)

function add_marker(svg) {  
  var color = 'black'  
  svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id","arrowhead")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 7)
    .attr("orient","auto")
    .attr('refX',5)
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 5 2 L 0 4 z")
    .style("fill", color);
}

function px(r,a) {
  return r*Math.cos(a*Math.PI/180)
}
function py(r,a) {
  return r*Math.sin(a*Math.PI/180)
}

function draw() {
  var r = 5
  var dots = [0,60,120,180,240,300,360]
  var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${r+2},${r+2})`)
  
  const qbPath = index => {
    const from  = dots[(index + 1) % dots.length];
    const to = dots[index];
    const x1 = px(r,from);
    const y1 = py(r,from);
    const x2 = px(r,to);
    const y2 = py(r,to);
    const mx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    const my = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    const dx = (x2 - mx);
    const dy = (y2 - my);
    const x3 = mx - dy * 1.5;
    const y3 = my + dx * 1.5;
    
    const dist = Math.hypot(x3-x1, y3-y1);
    const cx1 = x1 + (x3 - x1) / dist;
    const cy1 = y1 + (y3 - y1) / dist;
    const cx2 = x2 + (x3 - x2) / dist;
    const cy2 = y2 + (y3 - y2) / dist;
    
    return `M ${cx1},${cy1} Q ${x3},${y3} ${cx2},${cy2}`;
  };
 

  var g1 = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(dots).enter()
  
  g1.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',d => px(r,d))
  .attr('cy',d => py(r,d))
  .attr('r',1)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  
  var prev = null
  var mydraw = function(d,i) {
    if (prev == null) {
      prev = d
      return ''
    }
    var x1 = px(r,d)
    var y1 = py(r,d)
    var x2 = px(r,prev)
    var y2 = py(r,prev)
    var x3 = px(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var y3 = py(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var path = `M ${x1},${y1} Q ${x3},${y3} ${x2},${y2}`
    prev = d
    return path
  }
  /*
  g1.append('path')
  .attr('d',d => mydraw(d))
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  .attr("marker-end","url(#arrowhead)")
  */
  g1.filter((_, i) => i > 0)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', (_, i) => qbPath(i))
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('stroke-width',.1)
    .attr("marker-end","url(#arrowhead)")
}
function add_grid(svg) {
  var mygrid = function(d) {
    return `M 0,${d} l ${w},0 M ${d},0 l 0,${w}`
  }

  var grid = []
  for(var i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    grid.push(i);
  }

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(grid).enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d',d => mygrid(d))
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','green')
    .attr('stroke-width',.05)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer, one more bug is if change the arrow to red, then I can see the black line has a little bit on the end!

Answer (score 1):

Two more fixes:

1. In the arrow marker `.attr('refX',4)` instead of 5
2. In `qbPath` increase radius of the end point (you can change 1.1 to any value greater then 1):

```
const cx2 = x2 + (x3 - x2) / dist * 1.1;
const cy2 = y2 + (y3 - y2) / dist * 1.1;
```

```js
var w = 15

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width','500')
.attr('height','500')
.attr('viewBox',`0 0 ${w} ${w}`)
//.style('border','1px solid red')
add_marker(svg)
add_grid(svg)
draw(svg)

function add_marker(svg) {  
  var color = 'red'  
  svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id","arrowhead")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 7)
    .attr("orient","auto")
    .attr('refX',4)
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 5 2 L 0 4 z")
    .style("fill", color);
}

function px(r,a) {
  return r*Math.cos(a*Math.PI/180)
}
function py(r,a) {
  return r*Math.sin(a*Math.PI/180)
}

function draw() {
  var r = 5
  var dots = [0,60,120,180,240,300,360]
  var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${r+2},${r+2})`)
  
  const qbPath = index => {
    const from  = dots[(index + 1) % dots.length];
    const to = dots[index];
    const x1 = px(r,from);
    const y1 = py(r,from);
    const x2 = px(r,to);
    const y2 = py(r,to);
    const mx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    const my = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    const dx = (x2 - mx);
    const dy = (y2 - my);
    const x3 = mx - dy * 1.5;
    const y3 = my + dx * 1.5;
    
    const dist = Math.hypot(x3-x1, y3-y1);
    const cx1 = x1 + (x3 - x1) / dist;
    const cy1 = y1 + (y3 - y1) / dist;
    const cx2 = x2 + (x3 - x2) / dist * 1.1;
    const cy2 = y2 + (y3 - y2) / dist * 1.1;
    
    return `M ${cx1},${cy1} Q ${x3},${y3} ${cx2},${cy2}`;
  };
 

  var g1 = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(dots).enter()
  
  g1.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',d => px(r,d))
  .attr('cy',d => py(r,d))
  .attr('r',1)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  
  var prev = null
  var mydraw = function(d,i) {
    if (prev == null) {
      prev = d
      return ''
    }
    var x1 = px(r,d)
    var y1 = py(r,d)
    var x2 = px(r,prev)
    var y2 = py(r,prev)
    var x3 = px(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var y3 = py(r*1.8,(prev+d)/2)
    var path = `M ${x1},${y1} Q ${x3},${y3} ${x2},${y2}`
    prev = d
    return path
  }
  /*
  g1.append('path')
  .attr('d',d => mydraw(d))
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','black')
  .attr('stroke-width',.1)
  .attr("marker-end","url(#arrowhead)")
  */
  g1.filter((_, i) => i > 0)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', (_, i) => qbPath(i))
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('stroke-width',.1)
    .attr("marker-end","url(#arrowhead)")
}
function add_grid(svg) {
  var mygrid = function(d) {
    return `M 0,${d} l ${w},0 M ${d},0 l 0,${w}`
  }

  var grid = []
  for(var i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    grid.push(i);
  }

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(grid).enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d',d => mygrid(d))
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','green')
    .attr('stroke-width',.05)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```